# How to troubleshoot a server having SFTP, SCP transfer speeds of around 500 KB/s with many but not all machines?

Tags: linux, sftp, scp, file-transfer, network-speed

We have two Ubuntu servers that have very slow upload and download SFTP, SCP, and RSYNC speeds, around 500 KB/s, when connecting from most home machines. These servers have fast corporate Internet access and are behind a corporate firewall.

The same home machines can have much faster transfer speeds to and from other servers, e.g. 10 MB/s. Also, some home machines connect to the two servers in question via VPN with speeds much higher than 500 KB/s.

The IT department assures that the VPN is not throttling any file transfers. They were initially not able to reproduce the slow transfer speed issue but eventually reproduced it from one of their own home laptops.

So far, the cause for the slow transfer speeds remains a mystery. How can this issue be troubleshooted?